# Trouble cloning a codecommit repository to Codebuild with ssh

Tags: git, ssh, expect, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

I need to get some files from multiple Codecommit repositories onto an Ubuntu Codebuild instance. So I'm trying to clone the repos using ssh authentication. I've already set up the ssh keys and the config file on the instance, the trouble comes up when I do a `git clone`. I'm using `expect` to respond to the first time ssh connection prompt. Here's my expect script, `cloneRepo.sh` :

> #!/usr/bin/expect
>
> set timeout 20
>
> spawn git clone
>   ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/myrepo
>   /tmp/myrepo
>
> expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" { send
>   "yes\r" }
>
> expect "Resolving deltas: 100% (*/*), done." {}
>
> interact

Everything looks okay when I run it in Codebuild:

> [Container]  Running command echo "Cloning Git repositories"
>   Cloning Git repositories
>
> [Container]  Running command sudo ./cloneRepo.sh
>   spawn git clone ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/myrepo /tmp/myrepo
>   Cloning into '/tmp/myrepo'...
>   The authenticity of host 'git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' can't be established.
>   RSA key fingerprint is a6:9c:7d:bc:35:f5:d4:5f:8b:ba:6f:c8:bc:d4:83:84.
>   Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
>   Warning: Permanently added 'git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
>
> remote:
>   remote: Counting objects: 0
>   remote: Counting objects: 40, done.
>   Receiving objects:   2% (1/40)
>   ...
>   Receiving objects: 100% (40/40)
>   Receiving objects: 100% (40/40), 6.66 KiB | 6.66 MiB/s, done.
>   Resolving deltas:   0% (0/20)
>   ...
>   Resolving deltas: 100% (20/20), done.
>   Resolving deltas: 100% (20/20)

However, `/tmp/` remains empty:

> [Container]  Running command ls -la /tmp/
>   total 8
>   drwxrwxrwt  2 root root 4096 Aug  1 02:04 .
>   drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4096 Aug  1 02:02 ..

---

It looks like some sort of permissions error, but I just can't put my finger on it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: enable debugging by adding `exp_internal 1` before `spawn` and see if there's anything wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem by adding `sleep 10` before the `interact` in the expect script.
I think the clone process didn't completely finish when the expect script ended and Codebuild continued to run regardless. Adding the pause allows the clone to finish.